# undefined reference with std::atomic<const memberfunctionpointer*>::store() in g++ 4.4

Tags: c++, linker, c++11, g++

I have a `std::atomic` which contains a pointer to a member function. Everything compiles fine in g++ 4.4.5, but I get this error during linking:

```
./pool.o: In function `pool::worker::worker(pool&, int, int)':
pool.cpp:(.text._ZN4pool6workerC1ERS_ii[pool::worker::worker(pool&, int, int)]+0x95): undefined reference to `std::atomic<void (pool::* const*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*)>::store(void (pool::* const*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*), std::memory_order) volatile'
./pool.o: In function `pool::worker::give_job(void (pool::* const&)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*), unsigned int, unsigned int)':
pool.cpp:(.text._ZN4pool6worker8give_jobERKMS_FvjjPS0_Ejj[pool::worker::give_job(void (pool::* const&)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*), unsigned int, unsigned int)]+0x142): undefined reference to `std::atomic<void (pool::* const*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*)>::store(void (pool::* const*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*), std::memory_order) volatile'
./pool.o: In function `pool::worker::soul()':
pool.cpp:(.text._ZN4pool6worker4soulEv[pool::worker::soul()]+0xf1): undefined reference to `std::atomic<void (pool::* const*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*)>::store(void (pool::* const*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, pool::worker*), std::memory_order) volatile'
```

I don't really undertand why it's trying to link to the volatile overloads of `store()`, where in the source the pointer to the member function is `const`, not `volatile` (and it compiles).

The same code compiles with g++ 4.6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: GCC 4.4 didn't have support for this or it is broken in the way you experienced. Newer GCC has better support and it works like it should.

Comment: There is: use a newer GCC. It's not even a workaround, it's common sense `;)`

Comment: I care about backward compatibility. Latest Debian still runs 4.4 (and that's pretty much the reason for which noticed this bug).

Comment: @LorenzoPistone then you shouldn't have used C++11 features not fully functional with that GCC. And Debian has `testing` GCC 4.5-4.7 packages if you need em.

Comment: "I care about backward compatibility" contradicts your use of a feature documented as ["**Important:** GCC's support for C++11 is still **experimental**. Some features were implemented based on early proposals, and no attempt will be made to maintain backward compatibility when they are updated to match the final C++11 standard."](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) Especially when using a compiler released before the final standard.